# UIActivityIndicatorView (spinner) wont show or stop after loading remote json data

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I’m working on an app with Core Data and after local data is preloaded, it fires off the loading of json data from S3 url. So, i’d like to show the spinner because for some reason it takes an average of 8 seconds to show data in(blank frozen tableview), so I need to display a gray spinner (activity indicator)and properly stop it when the data finish loading.
The remote data will start syncing with server at a number of seconds previously preset (I set it to 4hrs. to not create so many requests during workshop sessions) and fire off the server load in AppDelegate’s applicationDidBecomeActive.

The thing is, I’m experiencing issues with the spinner to show it when data is being loaded / stop indicator when done showing data rows, hence the blank tableview is still blocking the UI.

Case1) spinner is started in viewDidLoad, and stopped(in main thread) in controllerDidChangeContent. result: i don't see spinner and it seems data is still loading, so it shows blank tableview with no spinner - In this case, or it’s too fast or it appears that controllerDidChangeContent finishes before data is done loading.

Case 2) spinner starts in viewWillAppear and stopped in viewWillDissapear. It shows spinning view at the right time in the right screen, but only stops if user changes views.

Case 3) Then I tried using flags. Like, isLoading equals true and making it false to stop spinner.

```js
#AppDelegate

func updateSeedJsonFromServer() {
        
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:seedLoadURL)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            
   var error: NSError? = nil            
            
   let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSArray            
            
   let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EventModel", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
            
                for jsonDictionary in jsonArray {
                
                    let eventSectionDate = jsonDictionary["eventSectionDate"] as! String
                    let priority = jsonDictionary["priority"] as! NSNumber
                    let room = jsonDictionary["room"] as! String
                    let sessionDate = jsonDictionary["sessionDate"] as! String
                    let desc = jsonDictionary["desc"] as! String
                    let sessionTitle = jsonDictionary["sessionTitle"] as! String
                    let speaker = jsonDictionary["speaker"] as! String
                    let breakDate = jsonDictionary["breakDate"] as! String
                    let isFavorite = jsonDictionary["isFavorite"] as! Bool
                
                    let newEvent = EventModel(entity: entity!,
                        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
                    newEvent.eventSectionDate = eventSectionDate
                    newEvent.priority = priority
                    newEvent.room = room
                    newEvent.sessionDate = sessionDate
                    newEvent.desc = desc
                    newEvent.sessionTitle = sessionTitle
                    newEvent.speaker = speaker
                    newEvent.breakDate = breakDate
                    newEvent.isFavorite = NSNumber(bool:isFavorite)
                }
            
                self.managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
               
                println("Imported \(jsonArray.count) events from server...")
            //Go ahead and set a lastServerCheck value
            
//            stop spinner here?
            
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "lastServerCheck")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }

/////
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

        //kick off background refresh from server if hasn't been too soon, when app becomes active
        let tooSoonSeconds: NSTimeInterval = 60 * 240 // 4h
        
        if endOfTimeDate.compare(NSDate()) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            let lastServerCheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("lastServerCheck") as? NSDate ?? begginingOfTimeDate
               
            if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastServerCheck) > tooSoonSeconds {
                
                let fetchserverRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EventModel")
                var error: NSError? = nil
                let results = managedObjectContext?.countForFetchRequest(fetchserverRequest, error: &error)
                if (results != nil) {
                    if let results = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchserverRequest, error: &error) {
                      
                        for obj in results {
                            let e = obj as! EventModel
                            managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(e)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
                }
                
//                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.updateSeedJsonFromServer()
                        println("Firing off updateFromServer...")
                
                
//                    })
            
                
            }else {
                //Not checking with server at the moment-
                println("NOT checking with the server right now at \(NSDate()); last check was \(lastServerCheck)")
                
            }
            
        } else {
            //Kill switch ON-
            println("Not checking anymore with aws server  - Kill switch ON")
        }
       
 }
```

In ScheduleViewController, I call this funcs in prev. mentioned places:

```js
func startSpinner() {
        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .Gray
        spinner.center = self.view.center
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.parentViewController?.view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        
    }
 
###
    func stopSpinner() {
        if !isLoading {
            if self.spinner.isAnimating() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    println("spinner stopping...")
                    
                   // self.tableView.reloadData()
                    println("reloading table...")
                })
            }
        }
    
    }
```

The right place, I guess, should be right after the task resume line gets called out, but I can’t insert the spinner stop function in the AppDelegate’s applicationDidBecomeActive because it doesn’t know about the UIActivityIndicatorView in there. I’ve tried creating a swift class just for the spinner, so it throws red errors because it doesn’t recognize UIViews, even importing UIKit.

Where would I set the spinner's start & stop functions when the syncing is done in AppDelegate? I appreciate your help with this. If need more code, let me know. Thank you in advance.

NetworkSpinner.swift Cocoa class:

```js
import UIKit

class NetworkSpinner: NSObject {

    
    class func startSpinner(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView) {

        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .Gray
        spinner.center = self.view.center
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.parentViewController?.view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        
        
    }
   
}
```

Check the NewtorkSpinner class with the stopSpinner class method:

```js
class func stopSpinner(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView) {
        //use Local spinner var
        if spinner.isAnimating() {
            //put it on a main thread
          //  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                spinner.stopAnimating()
                
                println("spinner is stopping...")
          //  })
        }
        
    }
```

Do i need to send it to the main thread or even ask if the spinner isAnimating?

Comment: instead of using if isLoading == false you should use if !isLoading

Comment: @LeoDabus okay, will fix it. Where do I call the spinner if the json file is loading in Appdelegate.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the completion handler to show hide the spinner:

```
func updateSeedJsonFromServer() {

self.startSpinner()
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:seedLoadURL)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
//on the first line
self.stopSpinner()

}).resume()
```

Comment: the updateSeedJsonFromServer function is in AppDelegate, gives error- the AppDelegate doesn't have a member named startSpinner. The function startSpinner is in ScheduleViewController. If that is a possibility, how do I call startSpinner in AppDelegate? Tx -

Comment: Put the spinner in its own class so it can be called from anywhere

Comment: I tried before creating 1st) a cocoa class (inherited from NSObject), it gives NetworkSpinner.type does not have a member name view or parentViewController. 2nd) a Swift class file, same errors. See new code added.

Comment: Use UIWindow, so it can be displayed anywhere

Comment: class func startSpinner(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView) {

        spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .Gray
        let targetView = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow
        targetView.addSubView(spinner)
        targetView.bringSubViewToFront(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        
        
    }

Comment: I was able to set it at the center of the targetView ok, then spinner starts, but why it stops too early? the data is still loading. I tried calling stopSpinner class on first line and right after the println("Imported  x events from server..."). What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm going to mark it as accepted answer because you took your time to help me. I just need to figure this out, where to place the stopSpinner func to make it work properly. (when loading is finish)

Comment: Maybe an error is being returned in the completion block, what are the values of data, response and error?

Comment: I just figure it out, was calling the spinner class func in the wrong place. Since it takes about an average of 10 sec to display data from server, my next step would be to display an alert or loading message to the user.